# Как сделать так чтоб цикл возвращался сразу на первую когда я нажимаю 0 а не проходил все циклы и потом возвращался?

Tags: java, циклы, switch, case

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 //нам задали сделать меню с помоью цикла и switch case
 //нужно так чтоб она когда я нажимаю 0 возвращалось к первому циклу а не проходил все циклы и
 //потом возвращалась если запустите этото код то поймете в чем ошибка помогите пожалуйста
        System.out.println("Hi there!\n");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the menu of \"Salam Bro\" Fast Food Station.");
        System.out.println("Here you can see our menu below.");

        String basket = "";
        int price = 0;
        boolean IsTrue = true;
        while (IsTrue) {
            System.out.println("0. Exit.");
            System.out.println("1. Burgers.");
            System.out.println("2. Hot dogs.");
            System.out.println("3. French fries.");
            System.out.println("4. Drinks.");
            System.out.println("5. Sauces.");
            System.out.println("6. Additives.");
            System.out.println("7. Clear basket.");
            System.out.println("8. Check basket.");
            System.out.println("Choose one:");
            int Choose = sc.nextInt();

            do {
                 if (Choose == 1){
                System.out.println("1. Chicken hamburger - 590 kzt.");
                System.out.println("2. Beef hamburger - 790 kzt.");
                System.out.println("3. Chicken cheeseburger - 790 kzt.");
                System.out.println("4. Beef cheeseburger - 890 kzt.");
                System.out.println("5. Double chicken hamburger - 990 kzt.");
                System.out.println("6. Double chicken cheeseburger - 1090 kzt.");
                System.out.println("7. Double beef hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                System.out.println("8. Double beef cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                System.out.println("9. Mixed hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                System.out.println("10. Mixed cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                System.out.println("0. Exit.");}
                Choose = sc.nextInt();
                switch (Choose) {
                    case 1:
                        price = price + 590;
                        System.out.println("1. Chicken hamburger - 590 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        price = price = 790;
                        System.out.println("2. Beef hamburger - 790 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        price = price + 790;
                        System.out.println("3. Chicken cheeseburger - 790 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        price = price + 890;
                        System.out.println("4. Beef cheeseburger - 890 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        price = price + 990;
                        System.out.println("5. Double chicken hamburger - 990 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        price = price + 1090;
                        System.out.println("6. Double chicken cheeseburger - 1090 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        price = price + 1090;
                        System.out.println("7. Double beef hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        price = price + 1190;
                        System.out.println("8. Double beef cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        price = price + 1190;
                        System.out.println("9. Mixed hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        price = price + 1090;
                        System.out.println("10. Mixed cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        System.out.println("0. Exit.");
                        break;
                }System.out.println("Vash zakaz " +price);
            }
            while(Choose != 0);


            do {

                Choose = sc.nextInt();
                if (Choose == 2)
                    System.out.println("1. Spicy hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                System.out.println("2. Hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                switch (Choose) {
                    case 1:
                        price = price + 590;
                        System.out.println("1. Spicy hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        price = price + 590;
                        System.out.println("2. Hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                        break;}System.out.println("Vash zakaz " +price);

            }while(Choose !=0);
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все достаточно просто:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //нам задали сделать меню с помоью цикла и switch case
        //нужно так чтоб она когда я нажимаю 0 возвращалось к первому циклу а не проходил все циклы и
        //потом возвращалась если запустите этото код то поймете в чем ошибка помогите пожалуйста
        System.out.println("Hi there!\n");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the menu of \"Salam Bro\" Fast Food Station.");
        System.out.println("Here you can see our menu below.");

        String basket = "";
        int price = 0;
        boolean IsTrue = true;
        x:while (IsTrue) {
            System.out.println("0. Exit.");
            System.out.println("1. Burgers.");
            System.out.println("2. Hot dogs.");
            System.out.println("3. French fries.");
            System.out.println("4. Drinks.");
            System.out.println("5. Sauces.");
            System.out.println("6. Additives.");
            System.out.println("7. Clear basket.");
            System.out.println("8. Check basket.");
            System.out.println("Choose one:");
            int Choose = sc.nextInt();

            do {
                if (Choose == 1) {
                    System.out.println("1. Chicken hamburger - 590 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("2. Beef hamburger - 790 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("3. Chicken cheeseburger - 790 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("4. Beef cheeseburger - 890 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("5. Double chicken hamburger - 990 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("6. Double chicken cheeseburger - 1090 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("7. Double beef hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("8. Double beef cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("9. Mixed hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("10. Mixed cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                    System.out.println("0. Exit.");
                }
                Choose = sc.nextInt();
                switch (Choose) {
                    case 0: continue x;
                    case 1:
                        price = price + 590;
                        System.out.println("1. Chicken hamburger - 590 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        price = price = 790;
                        System.out.println("2. Beef hamburger - 790 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        price = price + 790;
                        System.out.println("3. Chicken cheeseburger - 790 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        price = price + 890;
                        System.out.println("4. Beef cheeseburger - 890 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        price = price + 990;
                        System.out.println("5. Double chicken hamburger - 990 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        price = price + 1090;
                        System.out.println("6. Double chicken cheeseburger - 1090 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        price = price + 1090;
                        System.out.println("7. Double beef hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        price = price + 1190;
                        System.out.println("8. Double beef cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        price = price + 1190;
                        System.out.println("9. Mixed hamburger - 1090 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        price = price + 1090;
                        System.out.println("10. Mixed cheeseburger - 1190 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        System.out.println("0. Exit.");
                        break;
                }
                System.out.println("Vash zakaz " + price);
            } while (Choose != 0);

            do {

                Choose = sc.nextInt();
                if (Choose == 2) {
                    System.out.println("1. Spicy hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                }
                System.out.println("2. Hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                switch (Choose) {
                    case 0: continue x;
                    case 1:
                        price = price + 590;
                        System.out.println("1. Spicy hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        price = price + 590;
                        System.out.println("2. Hot dog - 590 kzt.");
                        break;
                }
                System.out.println("Vash zakaz " + price);

            } while (Choose != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное долго мучился а как сделать так чтоб когда я выбираю 2 например выходил 2 только один раз а дальше только заказы, и вы знаете как сделать пункты 7-8

Comment: Не за что. если про пункты 7,8 был вопрос, то я его не понял, в идеале добавьте полное описание задачи. Кроме того, ваш код оставляет желать лучшего. Такая степень вложенности и дублирования кода очень скоро загонят в вас в угол и вы перестанете понимать что происходит

Comment: спасибо но скажите понятнее что вам не понравился , мой опыт программмирования 3 дня и я еще не знаком с вашими терминологиями

Comment: боюсь, что для 3-дневного опыта любое объяснение будет непонятным. для начала нужно освоить хотя бы азы, в т.ч. терминологию, без этого никак. джава не сводится только к циклам и условным операторам и единственному методу мейн, в этом случае вам и бейсика хватит с головой.  освойтесь немного с теорией, попрактикуйтесь и возвращайтесь с новыми вопросами, потому как в комментариях объяснить даже азы абсолютно невозможно (для этого надо не одну книгу прочитать)

Comment: а вы про это ну короче нам просто сказали сделать с тем что мы прошли то есть только циклы if else и switch а то дадут читинг я посмотрел много способов которые гораздо легче делали но ниче не поделаешь

Comment: даже в этом случае не обязательно писать все в одном методе. полиморфизм тоже никто не отменял. все таки джава язык оопшный